# ExpandoObject in Dictionary is null value

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, null, expandoobject

I have a Dictionary that is filled with dynamic objects (Dictionary) in C# .NET 4.0. Sometimes the value is a string, an int or a float but sometimes the value is an ExpandoObject. The Dictionary itself is actually an ExpandoObject cast to a Dictionary for retrieving its properties.

The problem is, I'm iterating over each property of the main object (thus a Dictionary as well) and when there is an object of type ICollection/IList or ExpandoObject I want to perform an action. The problem however is that if there's an Dynamic Object (ExpandoObject) in the Dictionary it shows up as Null.

When I'm debugging in Visual Studio 2010 and  I open the Dynamic view it lists these objects as properties but when I'm looking at the same object's properties as Key Value pairs (looking at it from a Dictionary view), the value is "null" for when this objects holds other ExpandoObjects. And a Null will never check as a Collection/EpandoObject thus my condition fails.

I haven't encountered this error before when using ExpandoObjects so I'm quite curious as to why it sees the ExpandoObjects as null values.

```
//Function gets a List of ExpandoObjects (casting it as IDictionary)
    private static dynamic mergeIdObjects(List<IDictionary<string, dynamic>> objects)
    {          
        // Take first object as placeholder for the other objects
        IDictionary<string, dynamic> merged = (objects.First())[ParentObject];

        // For all objects to merge (except first one, already used that one as a placeholder)
        foreach (var o in objects.Skip(1))
        {
            IDictionary<string, dynamic> obj = o[ParentObject];
            // For all keys(property names) in the object)
            foreach (dynamic key in obj.Keys)
            {
                dynamic oldValue;

                // This is where the program doesn't function as it should.
                if (merged.TryGetValue(key, out oldValue)) // If key is already in merged object
                {
        // This never evaluates to True since the IList properties are now 'Null' and they shouldn't!
                    if (oldValue is IList<dynamic>) // If value is a list
                        merged[key].Add(obj[key]);  // then add item to this list
                    else
                        if (merged[key] != obj[key])   // Else create a list and add the item
                            merged[key] = new List<dynamic> { oldValue, obj[key] };
                }
                else
                    merged.Add(key, obj[key]);  // If this key is not in the merged object, add it to the merged object
            }
        }
        IDictionary<string, dynamic> placeHolder = new ExpandoObject();
        placeHolder.Add(ParentObject, merged);

        return (dynamic)placeHolder;
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing, a cast I've missed or maybe a wrong DataType used? I can't seem to figure it out and any help is kindly aprpeciated!